# Finding a limit with negative infinity (Square root)

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

I'm given this question $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty }\left(\sqrt{x}-\frac{2+x}{\sqrt{x}}\right) $$

My attempt,

$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty }(\sqrt{x}-\frac{2+x}{\sqrt{x}})=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty }(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}})$

How to I substitute negative infinity to square root of $x$? Wouldn't it be an imaginary number ?

Comment: In Real calculus, $\sqrt x$ is not defined for $x<0$

Comment: Where is this question from? $\sqrt{x}$ for $x\to-\infty$ seems at best... peculiar, in a question.

Comment: Rationalize both terms

Comment: @ArchisWelankar This is not the issue... the question is about taking the square root of a negative number.

Comment: It will be $2/{\sqrt\infty}{i}=0$ whats the issue Clement C

Comment: That traditionally, the symbol $\sqrt{}$ is associated with a function $\sqrt{}\colon\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ which is not defined for negative numbers. The fact that negative numbers can be written as the square of complex numbers does not mean that the function above is defined on negative numbers, especially in the context of real calculus. (in particular, the symbol $\sqrt{}$ is usually not used for that, from what I saw and am used to)

Comment: @ClementC. Assuming real numbers, there is an issue. However, I would assume that this particular course that the OP is taking will accept the use of complex numbers. Otherwise, I do not see why this question would be asked.

Comment: It might just be an instructor's carelessness in constructing exercises.  So, maybe it's unconventional, but the limit still exists and it is zero.